# Setting up Memcached for Django session caching on App Engine

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine, caching, memcached

when setting up Django to use Memcached for caching (in my case, I want to  to use session caching), in `settings.py` we set

```
CACHES = {
    'default': {
        'BACKEND': 'django.core.cache.backends.memcached.MemcachedCache',
        'LOCATION': '127.0.0.1:11211',
    }
}
```

I will be running the project in App Engine so my question is what do I do to for the `LOCATION` entry?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

As it happens, I have been porting a Django (1.6.5) application to GAE over the last few days (GAE Development SDK 1.9.6). I don't have a big need for caching right now but it's good to know it's available if I need it.

So I just tried using `django.core.cache.backends.memcached.MemcachedCache` as my cache backend (set up as you describe in your question, and I put python-memcached in my libs folder) and

```
SESSION_ENGINE = 'django.contrib.sessions.backends.cache'
```

to manage my sessions and GAE gave me the error:

```
RuntimeError: Unable to create a new session key. It is likely that the cache is unavailable.
```

### Anyway...

...even if you could get this to work it's surely better to use Google's API lib and borrow from the Django Memcached implementation, especially as the Google lib has been designed to be [compatible with python-memcached](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/memcache/clientclass) and otherwise your app could break at any time with an SDK update. Create a python module such as `my_project/backends.py`:

```
import pickle
from django.core.cache.backends.memcached import BaseMemcachedCache


class GaeMemcachedCache(BaseMemcachedCache):
    "An implementation of a cache binding using google's app engine memcache lib (compatible with python-memcached)"
    def __init__(self, server, params):
        from google.appengine.api import memcache
        super(GaeMemcachedCache, self).__init__(server, params,
                                             library=memcache,
                                             value_not_found_exception=ValueError)

    @property
    def _cache(self):
        if getattr(self, '_client', None) is None:
            self._client = self._lib.Client(self._servers, pickleProtocol=pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)
        return self._client
```

Then your cache setting becomes:

```
CACHES = {
    'default': {
        'BACKEND': 'my_project.backends.GaeMemcachedCache',
    }
}
```

That's it! This seems to work fine but I should be clear that it is not rigorously tested!

### Aside

Have a poke around in `google.appengine.api.memcache.__init__.py` in your GAE SDK folder and you will find:

```
  def __init__(self, servers=None, debug=0,
               pickleProtocol=cPickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL,
               pickler=cPickle.Pickler,
               unpickler=cPickle.Unpickler,
               pload=None,
               pid=None,
               make_sync_call=None,
               _app_id=None):
    """Create a new Client object.

    No parameters are required.

    Arguments:
      servers: Ignored; only for compatibility.
    ...
```

i.e. Even if you could find a `LOCATION` for your memcache instance in the cloud, Google's own library would ignore it.

Comment: this just might work. need to try it out tonight. If this works, the reputation points are yours :)

Comment: Yeah, looks to be a decent solution -- it's working on my end.

Answer (score 0):

The location should be set as your ip and port where your memcache daemon is running.

Check this in django official documentation.

> Set LOCATION to ip:port values, where ip is the IP address of the
>   Memcached daemon and port is the port on which Memcached is running,
>   or to a unix:path value, where path is the path to a Memcached Unix
>   socket file.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/cache/

Comment: Afraid not. The question is in the context of App Engine. In a managed environment, I simply don't have an IP address to point to nor a file for that matter.

Answer (score 0):

If you are following this documentation 
http://www.allbuttonspressed.com/projects/djangoappengine

And cloning this (as asked in the above link)
https://github.com/django-nonrel/djangoappengine/blob/master/djangoappengine/settings_base.py

**I don't think you need to define a location**. Is it throwing an error when you don't define it?

Comment: I have not tried w/o LOCATION but in a non-managed environment, I have always needed the LOCATION entry. I will try it out and hopefully you are right.

Comment: I was having the same issue as you -- the memcache client would throw an exception: ValueError: Unable to parse connection string: "". The fix was to actually just keep LOCATION pointing to '127.0.0.1:11211'. Seems to work for me!

Comment: I take that back, it wasn't working properly, it must have just fallen back to `LocMemCache` or something.