# Django cache vs App Engine cache - which one should I use?

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine, caching

I'm running Django (1.5) on App Engine and I need to use some kind of key-value cache. I know [App Engine's memcache API](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/memcache/usingmemcache?csw=1) and also the [Django's cache framework](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/cache/). I wonder which one should I use.

On one hand I would like my code to be as portable as possible for migrating it to another cloud platform. But on the other hand I would like to fully utilize the services offered by App Engine.

Is [writing a custom cache backend](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24785322/1795244) for Django that will use the App Engine memcache is the best solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tzach, I think you're already answering your question.

Putting your app in GAE and not using the services provided by Google *it doesn't look to me as a wise decision*, even more, when those features are key for performance at the same time free or very cheap.

On the other hand, the embedded default cache in Python is not guaranteed to give its best results under GAE, as GAE instances are not a normal server where you'd run your django instance, e.g. instances can be shutdown at any time.

These special characteristics found in Django are tuned in the django for GAE versions.

For that reason, and taking into account that using the GAE memcache is also  straightforward, *I'd recommend you using the easiest ones to add to your application*.

And, if in the future, you move to another platform, there will be more things to change than the key-value cache.

My two cents on that is *to focus firstly in getting the job done and secondly in optimizing the performance on GAE* and only afterwards to start thinking on things to improve.

Comment: Thanks Mario, I ended up using the custom backend from here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24785322/1795244, it works perfectly

Comment: That what's I was implying. To use what other people already create, and to support the community in other ways ;)