# How to setup memcached for Django 3.0 on App Engine?

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine, memcached, google-app-engine-python

So I have a Django 3.0 app that I want to deploy to App Engine. I want to use Memcached in order to cache data that has been pulled from BQ to my Django app. So far what I have is that I set up my Django's `views.py` as follows:

```py
from google.appengine.api import memcache

def index(request):
     cached_data = memcache.get('cached_data')
     
     if not cached_data:
          # Syntax to pull data here
          memcache.add(key='cached_data', value='pulled_data', time=3600)
```

My `app.yaml` also includes

```yaml
app_engine_apis: true
```

However, after deploying the app using `gcloud app deploy` and opening the web app, I'm getting a `500 Server Error`. I believe this error is because of the Memcached but I'm not sure what I am missing.

**Additional Note:** I have not set any `CACHES` in my `settings.py` as none were mentioned on the GCP website. I used this during development locally:

```py
CACHES = {
    'default': {
        'BACKEND': 'django.core.cache.backends.memcached.PyMemcacheCache',
        'LOCATION': '127.0.0.1:11211',
    }
}
```

But then I removed it right before deploying to App Engine.

I've tried following this [SO Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24699935/setting-up-memcached-for-django-session-caching-on-app-engine) but it didn't work for me.

**UPDATE 500 SERVER ERROR**
[image: Log 500 Server Error]

[image: Screenshot of the log 500 Server Error]

Comment: What is the output of your log (what is the output where it is reporting 500 server error)?

Comment: @NoCommandLine I've updated the post with the screenshot of the log from Google App Engine.

Comment: Did you include ```appengine-python-standard>=0.2.2``` in your ```requirements.txt``` file?

Answer (score 0):

I would discourage this option has it involves using the Python2 Google App Engine environment. Python2 is very legacy and currently is no longer supported by the community.

The best option would be to use the [Python3 runtime](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/runtime) and instead of Memcache use [Firestore](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/using-cloud-datastore) to store your data. Firestore is a NoSQL document database built for automatic scaling, high performance, and ease of application development.

Comment: By "Python2 Google App Engine environment" you mean the `app_engine_apis`? Plus, do you have any recommendation for guidance to use Firestore as a caching system in Django?

Comment: There are two runtimes for using Python on GAE, [Python2](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/runtime) and [Python3](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/runtime). I am not familiar with Django but if you would like to have a caching system maybe [Cloud Memorystore](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/using-memorystore) is a good choice for you.

Comment: @IIompalles - You can 'now' use memcache with Python3. That is the reason why OP has ```app_engine_apis: true``` in their ```app.yaml```